Grpc config errors
Ubuntu version Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Getting the below error on running make sandbox
CMake Error at src/sandbox/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "grpc" with any of
  the following names:

    grpcConfig.cmake
    grpc-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "grpc" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "grpc_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "grpc"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

My CMakelists.txt has
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(grpc CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC CONFIG REQUIRED)

Have seen different similar questions on stackoverflow as well as github forums, have not been able to resolve

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu being used.

Why are you trying to find it by both names (grpc and gRPC)? Does it work if you simply omit the former (since the file provided by package libgrpc-dev appears actually to be named gRPCConfig.cmake)

@steeldriver On a github forum someone mentioned it worked for them after they changed the cases.
I am asking here after checking many forums
Just now also have visited https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/ and followed the instructions there

OK but since you used REQUIRED the build will fail unless both the lower case and mixed case names are matched - AFAIK you need to pick the one that works and omit the other (unless you can come up with some kind of conditional construct to test both)

@steeldriver thank you still learning about CMake, have removed the not needed line
Thanks, your reply helped me yesterday too for a different question
